# Windows Server DHCP role not working correctly in VMware Player

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, dhcp, active-directory, vmware-player

I've got a Windows Server 2008 running in VMWare player with the following roles:

- Active Directory Domain Services
- DHCP
- DNS

The server is using the following credentials:

- The IP of the (DNS) server is `192.168.1.10`
- The name of the domain is `cva.local`

---

I've also got a pc running in VMWare Player with Windows 7 on it.

For configuration on this machine:

- I set the IPv4 address (manually) to `192.168.1.100`
- I set the DNS Server to (manually) `192.168.1.10`
- I joined the `cva.local` domain.

After this I was able to login with the users i've created in the active directory within the server.

This was also working.

---

When configurating the DHCP server I used the following settings:

- Scope name: `cva-scope`
- Start IP address: `192.168.1.100`
- End IP address: `192.168.1.200`
- Subnet mask: `255.255.255.0`
- 006 DNS Servers: `127.0.0.1`
- 015 DNS Domain Name: `cva.local`

I wasn't receiving any errors while setting this up.

---

**Problem**

When I went back to the Windows 7 client PC and navigated to the screen where I could change my IPv4 settings and I activated the following checkboxes:

- Obtain an IP address automatically
- Obtain DNS server address automatically

I received an IPv4 address and default gateway from my router's DHCP service (which is outside of VMWare).

**Expectation**

I want to receive an IPv4 address from the Windows server, within the range I set in the DHCP settings. I don't want to receive an default gateway, because i'm not expecting any internet access at this point.

**Question**

Which settings do I have to change in VMWare (or anywhere else?) to achieve the result above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the DHCP server on a separate network segment.

When starting, the Windows Server's DHCP Server Service checks if there are any other DHCP servers in the same network segment. If it detects one, it won't assign any IP addresses.

As far as I know you can't create any virtual network with VMware Player, so you'll need to use other virtualisation solution that supports virtual networks, temporarily disable the DHCP server on your router or use another router to divide the network into two segments - one with the router you have and the other with your virtual machines.

By the way, "006 DNS Servers" option should be configured with server's IP address (192.168.1.10) and not 127.0.0.1. With the current configuration, the client computer will send DNS queries to itself and not to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, but changing the network segment isnt an option in this case. This is for practice at my school, wich doesnt have the possibility to re-configure router settings :) The ip of my server computer is 192.168.1.10 (manually set) so that should be good right?

Comment: Yes, you should enter 192.168.1.10 in option "006 DNS Servers". As to the segmenting the network - if you do not need external network access during your practice, you can consider disconnectig from the school's router. Your DHCP settings should work, you can test and experiment with them. After you are done, reconfigure Windows 7 manual settings and connect your computer to the school network again.

Comment: yeah, but in this case its the same as 127.0.0.1 right?

Comment: No, 127.0.0.1 is always localhost. When a computer is connecting to 127.0.0.1 address it is connecting to itself. On your server 127.0.0.1 is the same as 192.168.1.10 and on your Windows 7 machine 127.0.0.1 is the same as 192.168.1.100.

Comment: Oow okay, did'nt know that. The standard configuration of the DHCP was setting that as standard value.

Comment: I suppose your server is configured with 127.0.0.1 as the primary DNS server, which is ok as the DNS service runs locally on the server. When you configured DHCP this setting was automatically copied to DHCP 006 option.